# Assemly stdcall parameters after @

Tags: assembly, stdcall

For what in assembly's procedure stdcall we need to write number of parameters(in bytes) after @? I mean... Anyway we will write "ret numberOfParameters" to clean stack. So for what?

Comment: You don't have to, it's just usual practice so callers can tell from the symbol name how many bytes of arguments it expects. Also if it ever changes, it will cause linker error and not a mysterious runtime problem.

Comment: @Jester But I have a link error when I doen't write number of bytes.

Comment: That means one side expects the `@`. You can omit it if **both** caller and callee do it. Also some libraries provide both names.

Comment: Is someone able to edit that question into a clearer question?